# Will the providers of dynamically created embeds receive the embedding site's IP address?

Tags: php, ajax, embed

If content is not present at my site during initial server render, say i use PHP as a server scripting language, the embed is added through Ajax, does this content send my server IP to the content owner? say i'm embedding a YouTube video, does YouTube (let's say they care how many embeds you make) get my server's IP?

Thank you.

Comment: shortly yes... see HTTP request header fields

Answer (score 1):

AJAX calls are performed by the users browser so yes, they will be coming from the IP adres of the user and not your server.

Comment: The latter is true but not for the reason you state. It's the *embed* that is rendered in the user's browser and that's why the remote site gets the IP. Ajax calls generally can't go beyond the limits of their own originating domain.

Comment: Thanks for this correct comment. My answer was a little short.